# Can I set QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR behavior via API?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.6

Can I set the `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR 1` [behavior](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.6/highdpi.html) via an API call rather than by the environment variable? I want to detect if my Qt application is running on a high dpi screen, then set the scaling accordingly.

I have tried to set it at the very beginning of `main`, [which does not work](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocessenvironment.html#details)

```
QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment().insert("QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR", "1");
```

> It's meant to be used along with QProcess, to set the environment for
>   child processes. It cannot be used to change the current process's
>   environment.

Follow up of [Style sheets / Qt Designer support for high dpi screens?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35641742/356726)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following should work

> qputenv("QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR", "1");

Comment: Excellent, at least I now can check for high DPI and set the flag accordingly. Remark: I have to set this at a very early stage (first line of `main`, otherwise it does not show any effect).

Comment: i dont think you need to check for DPI, if you have lowdpi or highdpi thanks to the AUTO part of the variable it should work as expected automatically