# How to interpret QFontMetrics results?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qfontmetrics

I have a problem making sense of the values I get from `QFontMetrics`

```
// 43 characters        0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
static const QString s("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
// Hint: basically returns w->fontMetrics(); with w being my main application window
const QFontMetrics fm = CGuiUtility::currentFontMetrics();
const int w = fm.width(s);
const int h = fm.height();
return QSize(w, h);
```

With the following screen resolutions I get:

1. ) 1920/1080: 256/16
2. ) 3840/2160: 178/10 hi DPI support `qputenv("QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR", "1")`
3. ) 3840/2160: 536/32 no hi DPI support

My understanding is that I do get pixel width/height. I wonder why I get a so much smaller height with a hires resolution (see 2). I would rather expect it the other way around - using more pixels.

What I can see is that there is (almost) factor 2 between 1 and 3, which makes sense. But then (using 3, no DPI support) the UI is unreadable (too small because of hi DPI screen). So how does 2 fit in, which has some odd results.

Is anybody able to give a hint on the interpretation of those values?

Remark: Related to [Style sheets / Qt Designer support for high dpi screens?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35641742/356726) What I try to find is a reasonable width/height for my UI window on different resolutions/platforms

---

Good comments, I see. With hi-dpi Qt scales 1:3 using a "virtual screen" of 1280/780. I wonder if I can adjust that pixel ratio manually. In my very case it happens by setting `qputenv("QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR", "1")`. Is there a chance to set it to 2:1?

1. ) "Desktop w1920 w1080 - ratio: 1 | 80 chars: w560 h16 | 43 chars: w256 h16"
2. ) "Desktop w1280 w720 hi DPI ratio: 3 | 80 chars: w400 h10 | 43 chars: w178 h10"
3. ) "Desktop w3840 w2160 - ratio: 1 | 80 chars: w1200 h32 | 43 chars: w536 h32"

Comment: What is `CGuiUtility::currentFontMetricsF()` Google is not showing me any QT results, it normally finds the QT docs at top of page 1?

Comment: as said in the hint, it is a small utility function which finds my main application window, then returns `w->fontMetrics()` of that window. So it is the font metrics of the main application window.

Comment: Try and see `qDebug() << QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry(pMyWidget).size();` for that specific mode.

Comment: What is `w->devicePixelRatioF()` for each case?

Comment: And what is your Qt version? The HiDpi support changes a lot between versions.

Comment: Version is 5.9.2, thanks for all the comments. Clearer now, wonder if I can adjust the pixel ratio on high DPI screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the hints of AlexanderVX and SteackOverflow it is clear now.

1. "Desktop w1920 w1080 - ratio: 1 | 80 chars: w560 h16 | 43 chars:
   w256 h16"
2. "Desktop w1280 w720 hi DPI ratio: 3 | 80 chars: w400 h10 |
   43 chars: w178 h10"
3. "Desktop w3840 w2160 - ratio: 1 | 80 chars:
   w1200 h32 | 43 chars: w536 h32"

Therefor I close the topiy